# Using Win8.1Pro Batch: Unable to verify if BitLocker has already applied encryption

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, batch-file, bitlocker

I'm working on a script that assists in standardizing a Windows 8.1 Pro image. In this part I'm trying to verify if BitLocker has already encrypted the drive or not using the following script:

```
:VerifyEncryption
REM Verifies if the OS is encrypted
cls
echo Verifying if the primary drive is encrypted by BitLocker...
cd %SystemRoot%\system32
for /F "tokens=1*" %%G in ('MANAGE-BDE -STATUS ^| FIND /I "ENCRYPTION_METHOD:"') do ( 
  IF "%%H"=="NONE" (
      GOTO :ENCRYPT
  ) ELSE (
  GOTO :DONTENCRYPT
  )
)

:DONTENCRYPT
echo Encrypted.
pause
exit

:ENCRYPT
echo Not Encrypted.
pause
exit
```

No matter if the machine is encrypted or not, I always get "Encrypted". Even though I don't receive errors it is still defaulting to the next line without actually doing the check. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**IF** is case sensitive. You should use **IF /I** or match the case of the output of **manage-bde -status**:

```
IF "%%H"=="None"
```

Or, case insensitive:

```
IF /I "%%H"=="NONE"
```

Similarly, you also need to match the output of the command in this line:

```
for /F "tokens=1*" %%G in ('MANAGE-BDE -STATUS ^| FIND /I "ENCRYPTION_METHOD:"') do (
```

You are searching for **ENCRYPTION_METHOD:**, but need to search for **Encryption Method:** (remove the underscore). Due to the extra space, you'll also need to change **tokens=1*** to **tokens=2***::

```
for /F "tokens=2*" %%G in ('MANAGE-BDE -STATUS ^| FIND /I "ENCRYPTION METHOD:"') do (
```

Comment: Made cap changes, still saying it's encrypted when it's not :( Thank you, though! Learned something new with /I

Comment: @Sandfrog I updated the answer and verified on Win8.1 You were looking for Encyrption_Method with an underscore and doing a case-sensitive IF with the wrong case.

Answer (score 0):

This works on Windows 8, Windows 10 and Server 2012R2 (all 64-bit):

```
FOR /F "skip=10 tokens=2*" %%t in ('manage-bde c: -STATUS')
```

This one works on Windows 7 (64-bit):

```
FOR /F "skip=10 tokens=2*" %%t in ('manage-bde -STATUS')
```